# Problem rendering data from Local Storage in React App

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, json, rendering

I have problem with rendering data from local storage on every refresh or reload. It renders only hard coded data but not data that I save in LS. It shows data in LS but not rendering. If anyone could explain or tell me what is wrong or give me directions to do something better would be grateful.I am farely new in Reactand would apretiate for insights. I ve put some dummy data. I ve sent componnets which could affect.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
//COMPONENTS:
import ScrollToTop from "./components/ScrollToTop";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import NavBar from "./components/NavBar";
import PhoneBook from "./components/PhoneBook";

function App() {
  const date = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([
    {
      id: Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9),
      fullName: "Vekjko Petrovic",
      address: "121 Town Commons Way Phoenix, AZ, 45215",
      phone: 123_465_689,
      date,
    },
    {
      id: Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9),
      fullName: "Marko Petrovic",
      address: "Srbina 35, 11300 Smederevo Srbija",
      phone: 256_269_866,
      date,
    },
    {
      id: Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9),
      fullName: "Michael Jackson",
      address: "52 City St, Detroit, Mi, 46218",
      phone: 359_525_555,
      date,
    },
    {
      id: Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9),
      fullName: "Vanessa Parady",
      address: "11 Beogradska Beograd, SRB, 11000",
      phone: 123_465_689,
      date,
    },
  ]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const savedContacts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("contacts"));

    if (savedContacts) {
      setContacts(savedContacts);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("contacts", JSON.stringify(contacts));
  }, [contacts]);

  const [searchContact, setSearchContact] = useState("");

  const [theme, setTheme] = useState("dark");
  const changeTheme = () => {
    theme === "dark" ? setTheme("light") : setTheme("dark");
  };

  const addContact = (fullName, phone, address, email) => {
    const newContacts = {
      id: Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9),
      fullName,
      address,
      phone,
      email,
      date,
    };
    const newContact = [...contacts, newContacts];
    setContacts(newContact);
  };

  const deleteContact = (id) => {
    const remainedContacts = contacts.filter((item) => item.id !== id);
    setContacts(remainedContacts);
  };

  return (
    <div data-theme={theme} className="app-container">
      <ScrollToTop />
      <NavBar changeTheme={changeTheme} currentTheme={theme} />
      <Home />
      <PhoneBook
        contacts={contacts.filter((contact) =>
          contact.fullName.toLowerCase().includes(searchContact)
        )}
        handleAddContact={addContact}
        deleteContact={deleteContact}
        handleSearchContacts={setSearchContact}
      />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App; 

import React from "react";

import "../index.css";

//ASSETS:

import NewContact from "./NewContact";
import Contact from "./Contact";
import Search from "./Search";

function PhoneBook({
  contacts,
  handleAddContact,
  deleteContact,
  handleSearchContacts,
}) {
  return (
    <div id="phone_book" className="contacts-list">
      <Search handleSearchContacts={handleSearchContacts} />

      {contacts.map((contact) => {
        return (
          <Contact
            key={contact.id}
            id={contact.id}
            fullName={contact.fullName}
            address={contact.address}
            phone={contact.phone}
            email={contact.email}
            date={contact.date}
            deleteContact={deleteContact}
          />
        );
      })}

      <NewContact handleAddContact={handleAddContact} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default PhoneBook;

import React from "react";
import profile from "../assets/images/profile.png";
import { MdDeleteForever } from "react-icons/md";
function Contact({ fullName, address, phone, email, id, date, deleteContact }) {
  return (
    <div className="contact">
      <p className="contact-header">
        <span>
          <i>{fullName} </i>
        </span>
        <img src={profile} alt="profile" />
      </p>
      <div className="contact-footer">
        <p>
          {" "}
          <i>Address: </i>
          {address}
        </p>
        <p>
          <i>Phone:</i> {phone}
        </p>
        <p>
          {" "}
          <i>Email:</i> {email}
        </p>
        <MdDeleteForever
          onClick={() => deleteContact(id)}
          className="delete-icon"
          size="1.3rem"
        />
        <p className="span-date">
          <i>Date: </i>
          {date}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Contact;

import React, { useState } from "react";

function NewContact({ handleAddContact }) {
  const [fullName, setFullName] = useState("");
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState("");
  const [address, setAddress] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");

  const handleSaveClick = () => {
    if (!(fullName.trim().length > 0)) {
      return;
    }
    handleAddContact(fullName, phone, address, email);
    setFullName("");
    setPhone("");
    setAddress("");
    setEmail("");
  };

  return (
    <div className="contact new last">
      {" "}
      <p className="inputs">
        <span>Create New Contact</span>

        <label>Full Name:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter..."
          value={fullName}
          onChange={(e) => setFullName(e.target.value)}
        />
        <label> Address:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter..."
          value={address}
          onChange={(e) => setAddress(e.target.value)}
        />
        <label> Phone:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter..."
          value={phone}
          onChange={(e) => setPhone(e.target.value)}
        />
        <label>Email:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter..."
          value={email}
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
        />
      </p>
      {/* <img src={profile} alt="fullname" /> */}
      <div className="save-list-footer">
        <button className="save" onClick={handleSaveClick}>
          SAVE
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default NewContact;
import styled from "styled-components";
import React from "react";
import { MdSearch } from "react-icons/md";

//STYLES
import "../index.css";

function Search({ handleSearchContacts }) {
  return (
    <SearchComponent className="search">
      <MdSearch className="search-icon" size="1.3em" />
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search..."
        onChange={(e) => handleSearchContacts(e.target.value)}
      />
    </SearchComponent>
  );
}
export default Search;
```

Answer (score 0):

Took me some messing around but I think I have an example that might be doing what you are describing. It seems like the following code may be the culprit:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("contacts", JSON.stringify(contacts));
  }, [contacts]);
```

Not in your example I assume you are initializing contacts like such:

```
const [contact, setContacts] = useState([])
```

When this state is initialized it will trigger that useEffect and set the localStorage.setItem("contacts" , []) which will make it look like nothing is being rendered. I think the easiest fix would be to move the localStorage.setItem into the addContacts function.

Here is a simplified version of how to set it up:

```
export const Contacts = () => {
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const savedContacts = localStorage.getItem("contacts");

    if (savedContacts) {
      setContacts(JSON.parse(savedContacts));
    }
  }, []);

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   //This is your issue here Comment out this block and comment in the setItem in the addContact
  //  localStorage.setItem("contacts", JSON.stringify(contacts));
  // }, [contacts]);

  const addContact = (newContact) => {
    const newContactList = [...contacts, newContact];
    setContacts(newContactList);
    localStorage.setItem("contacts", JSON.stringify(newContactList));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <InputContact addContact={addContact} />
      {contacts.map((data, i) => (
        <Contact data={data} key={i} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

You can find a working example of this on code sandbox. There is some explanation of the app in the App.js and Contacts.jsx. https://codesandbox.io/s/localstorage-contacts-s9dfzc?file=/src/Contacts.jsx:130-969

Comment: Thank you so much for your precious time and pointing me to right directions. Sorry for my late answer. God bless you, sir.